# Хочу, чтобы printf вывел число, а выводит символ из таблицы ASCII

Tags: fasm, printf

```
format pe console
include 'C:\Program Files\FASM\INCLUDE\win32ax.inc'
include 'C:\Program Files\FASM\INCLUDE\api\kernel32.inc'
entry start


.data
i db 40


.code
start:  cinvoke printf, <i>
        cinvoke getch
        invoke ExitProcess, 0


section '.idata' import data readable
library kernel32,'kernel32.dll',msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
import msvcrt, printf, 'printf', getch, '_getch', scanf, 'scanf'
```

Есть у меня, например, метка i со значением 40. Когда я запускаю программу, выводится "(". Я попробовал заменить `cinvoke printf, <i>` на `cinvoke printf, <'%d'>, i`, но у меня выводится число 4202496, a должно  выводиться 40. Как вывести число?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь `i` - это адрес в памяти, а не значение по указанной метке. Чтобы получить значение(40), вам нужно взять `i` в квадратные скобки `[i]`. Только переменная в данном случае размером в байт, и этот байт нельзя передавать в виде аргумента функции `printf()` - его нужно сначала преобразовать в DWORD, т.к. именно дворд = мин.значение для стека (иначе он уйдёт с границы 4-байт). Из байта/ворда делает дворд инструкция `movzx`. Вот пример:

```
format pe console
include 'win32ax.inc'
entry start
;//------------
.data
a         db  40       ;//<--- байт нельзя ложить в стек
b         dw  5583     ;//<--- ворд нельзя ложить в стек
c         dd  4953728  ;//<--- дворд можно
string    db  10,' Press any key for exit...',0
;//------------
.code
start:   invoke  SetConsoleTitle,<'*** Printf example ***',0>

         movzx   eax,[a]     ;//<--- делаем из байта дворд
         movzx   ebx,[b]     ;//<--- делаем из ворда дворд

        cinvoke  printf,<10,' Address    | Value   ',\
                         10,' -----------|---------',\
                         10,' 0x%08x   %d',\
                         10,' 0x%08x   %d',\
                         10,' 0x%08x   %d',\
                         10,' %s',0>,a,eax,b,ebx,c,[c],string  ;//<--- все аргументы размером DWORD
        cinvoke  getch
        cinvoke  exit,0
;//------------
section '.idata' import data readable
library  kernel32,'kernel32.dll',msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
import   msvcrt,printf,'printf',getch,'_getch',scanf,'scanf',exit,'exit'
include  'api\kernel32.inc'
```

[image: Результат]